# Circumference in a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1810129/what-is-the-circumference-of-a-complex-unit-circle#1810139) I learnt that the circumference of a unit circle in a complex plane is just the circumference of any normal circle $2\pi r$.

Now I would like to **take into account the imaginary character of intervals on the imaginery axis.** For this purpose I draw a circle in a complex plane, with the radius of one unit, and I get something that is no real circle because its radius is varying between 1 and i, depending on the direction of the radius. What would be the circumference of such a "circle"? I guess that it might be **$\frac{\pi}{2} (1+i) $**. Is my guess right?

**Edit:**
The assumption of @Irregular User:

> Similarly, if you measure the radius of your circle in the complex
>   plane in the direction of y-axis positively increasing, then you see
>   that your circle meets the y-axis at i. But the circle still has
>   radius 1.

misunderstands my question, because I want to take into account the complex character of intervals on the imaginary axis. If I draw a circle on a complex plane I don't get a circle, because its horizontal radius is one, but its vertical radius is i.

Comment: Radius is varying between Abs(1) = 1 and Abs(i) = 1

Comment: It is a little unclear to me what you mean. The radius should not be "varying" since otherwise the resulting figure would not be a circle. If the radius is fixed at length $1$, it will remain the same as the angle changes.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, you're saying that if you measure the radius of your circle in the complex plane in the direction of $x$-axis positively increasing, then you see that your circle meets the $x$-axis at $1$ and thus has radius $1$.

Similarly, if you measure the radius of your circle in the complex plane in the direction of $y$-axis positively increasing, then you see that your circle meets the $y$-axis at $i$. But the circle still has radius $1$.

Remember, when you look at the radius in this way, you must take the absolute value of what you've read off the axis. In a more familiar setting to you, when you look at a unit circle in the real plane, the circle also hits the $x$-axis and $y$-axis at $-1$ and $-1$. But this doesn't mean that the circle has a radius of $-1$. Again, we take the absolute value of $-1$, i.e. $|-1| = 1$.

Similarly, in our setting of the complex plane, $|1| = |-1| = |i| = |-i| = 1$.